# how to setup the sphinx4 with notepad

Tags: java, cmusphinx

can any one please help me how to setup sphinx4 with notepad. It's being few days now that I m trying to run the HelloWorld example and it doesn't work. I have set all the libs in ../jre/lib/ext folder but **I still get the following error.**

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/cmu/sphinx/util/p
rops/ConfigurationManager

```
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:33)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.Configura
tionManager

```
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more*
```

**HelloWorld.java:33 is the following line :**

cm = new ConfigurationManager(HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml"));

Can anyone give me a hand, please?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.assembla.com/code/sonido/subversion/nodes/sphinx4/src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo?rev=3
And check if all libraries (jars) are connected.